# react-native build release android BUILD FAILED duplicate entry zza.class

Tags: react-native

My react-native app use react-native-fcm and react-native-maps, it work well on debug but FAILED when assembleRelease

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zza.class

my android/app/build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

and android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Any solution please.

Comment: Both react-native-fcm and react-native-maps use play-service 9.4.0
I try to add 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
to dependencies but its doesnt  work :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: go to node_modules/react-native-maps/android/build.gradle and edit version to :+  and its work :D

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
}
```